# Python - Check if two trips(dates) overlap

Tags: python, class, methods

I have to check if two trips overlap using methods I have already written. I cannot import anything except for my own Date class. This is my code

```
class Date:
    """
    A class for establishing a date.
    """
    min_year = 1800

    def __init__(self, month = 1, day = 1, year = min_year):
        """
        Checks to see if the date is real.
        """
        self.themonth = month
        self.theday = day
        self.theyear = year
        monthdays = [31, 29 if self.year_is_leap() else 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

        if self.themonth < 1 or self.themonth > 12:
            raise Exception("Not a valid month")
        elif self.theday > monthdays[self.themonth-1] or self.theday > 31 or self.theday < 1:
            raise Exception("Not a valid day")
        elif self.theyear < self.min_year:
            self.theyear = self.min_year

    def month(self):
        """
        A function for returning the month of Date.
        """
        return self.themonth

    def day(self):
        """
        A function for returning the day of Date.
        """
        return self.theday

    def year(self):
        """
        A function for returning the year of Date.
        """
        return self.theyear

    def year_is_leap(self):
        """
        Returns true if date is a leap year, false otherwise.
        """
        if self.theyear % 4 == 0 and self.theyear % 100 != 0 or self.theyear %400 == 0:
            return True
        else:
                return False

    def daycount(self):
        """
        Returns the amount of days between two dates.
        """
        counter = 0
        m = Date(self.themonth, self.theday, self.theyear)
        monthdays = [31, 29 if m.year_is_leap() else 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

        for x in range(self.min_year, m.theyear):
            y = Date(self.themonth, self.theday, x)
            if y.year_is_leap() == True:
                counter += 366
            else:
                counter += 365
        daysthisyear = self.theday + sum(monthdays[0:self.themonth-1])
        counter += daysthisyear
        return counter

    def day_of_week(self):
        """
        Returns the day of the week for a real date.
        """
        z = Date(self.themonth, self.theday, self.theyear)
        if z.daycount() % 7 == 0: return str('Wednesday')
        if z.daycount() % 7 == 1: return str('Tuesday')
        if z.daycount() % 7 == 2: return str('Monday')
        if z.daycount() % 7 == 3: return str('Sunday')
        if z.daycount() % 7 == 4: return str('Saturday')
        if z.daycount() % 7 == 5: return str('Friday')
        if z.daycount() % 7 == 6: return str('Thursday')

    def __repr__(self):
        """
        Returns the date.
        """
        return '%s/%s/%s' % (self.themonth, self.theday, self.theyear)

    def nextday(self):
        """
        Returns the date of the day after given date.
        """
        m = Date(self.themonth, self.theday, self.theyear)
        monthdays = [31, 29 if m.year_is_leap() else 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
        maxdays = monthdays[self.themonth-1]

        if self.theday != maxdays:
            return Date(self.themonth, self.theday+1, self.theyear)
        elif self.theday == maxdays and self.themonth == 12:
            return Date(1,1,self.theyear+1)
        elif self.theday == maxdays and self.themonth != 12:
            return Date(self.themonth+1, 1, self.theyear)

    def prevday(self):
        """
        Returns the date of the day before given date.
        """
        m = Date(self.themonth, self.theday, self.theyear)
        monthdays = [31, 29 if m.year_is_leap() else 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
        if self.theday == 1 and self.themonth == 1 and self.theyear == 1800:
            raise Exception("No previous date available.")
        if self.theday == 1 and self.themonth == 1 and self.theyear != 1800:
            return Date(12, monthdays[11], self.theyear-1)
        elif self.theday == 1 and self.themonth != 1:
            return Date(self.themonth -1, monthdays[self.themonth-1], self.theyear)
        elif self.theday != 1:
            return Date(self.themonth, self.theday - 1, self.theyear)

    def __add__(self, n):
        """
        Returns a new date after n days are added to given date.
        """
        g = self.nextday()
        for x in range(1, n):
            g = g.nextday()
        return g

    def __sub__(self, n):
        """
        Returns a new date after n days are subtracted from given date.
        """
        h = self.prevday()
        for y in range(1,n):
            h = h.prevday()
        return h

    def __lt__(self, other):
        """
        Returns True if self comes before other, False otherwise.
        """
        if self.theyear == other.theyear:
            if self.themonth < other.themonth:
                return True
            elif self.themonth == other.themonth:
                if self.theday < other.theday:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            elif self.themonth > other.themonth:
                return False
        if self.theyear < other.theyear:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """
        Returns True if self and other are the same dates, False otherwise.
        """
        if self.theyear == other.theyear:
            if self.themonth == other.themonth:
                if self.theday == other.theday:
                    return True
        else:
            return False

    def __le__(self, other):
        """
        Returns True if self comes before or is the same as other, False otherwise.
        """
        if self.theyear == other.theyear:
            if self.themonth < other.themonth:
                return True
            elif self.themonth == other.themonth:
                if self.theday < other.theday:
                    return True
                elif self.theday == other.theday:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        if self.theyear < other.theyear:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __gt__(self, other):
        """
        Returns True if self comes after other, False otherwise.
        """
        if self.theyear == other.theyear:
            if self.themonth > other.themonth:
                return True
            elif self.themonth == other.themonth:
                if self.theday > other.theday:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        if self.theyear > other.theyear:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def __ge__(self, other):
        """
        Returns True if self comes after or is the same as other.
        """
        if self.theyear == other.theyear:
            if self.themonth > other.themonth:
                return True
            elif self.themonth == other.themonth:
                if self.theday > other.theday:
                    return True
                elif self.theday == other.theday:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        if self.theyear > other.theyear:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        """
        Returns True if self and other are unequal, False otherwise.
        """
        if self.theyear != other.theyear:
            if self.themonth != other.themonth:
                if self.theday != other.theday:
                    return True
        else:
            return False
    from date import *
class Trip:
    """
    Stores the date and duration of employees' trips.
    """

    def __init__(self, destination = None, depdate=Date(1, 1, 2015), duration=1):
        """
        Set the destination, when, and how long it will be.
        """
        self.thedestination = destination
        self.thedepdate = depdate
        self.theduration = duration

    def setDestination(self, newdestination):
        """
        This function lets the user change the destination.
        """
        self.thedestination = newdestination
        return self.thedestination

    def setDeparture(self, newdeparture):
        """
        This function lets the user change the departure date.
        """
        self.thedepdate = newdeparture
        return self.thedepdate

    def setDuration(self, newduration):
        """
        This function lets the user change the duration.
        """
        self.theduration = newduration
        return self.theduration

    def destination(self):
        """
        This function returns the destination of the trip.
        """
        return self.thedestination

    def departure(self):
        """
        This function returns the destination of the trip.
        """
        return self.thedepdate

    def duration(self):
        """
        This function returns the duration of the trip.
        """
        return self.theduration

    def arrival(self):
        """
        This function returns the date of arrival of a person's trip.
        """
        return self.thedepdate.__add__(self.theduration)

    def overlaps(self, other):
        """
        Returns True if the trips self and other overlap, False otherwise.
        """
        m = Trip(self.thedestination, self.thedepdate, self.theduration)
        g = self.thedepdate
        if self.thedepdate == other.thedepdate:
            return True
        while g != other.thedepdate:
            for x in range(1, self.theduration):
                g = self.thedepdate.nextday()
```

as you can see, my last function is the overlaps() method. What I have is what I came up with, but it doesn't work quite right. Obviously this is homework so I'm not looking for a spoon fed answer, but rather an explanation of how I can arrive at the answer. Thanks.

Comment: *"doesn't work quite right"*?! Do me a favour...

Comment: Please give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means (a) not all your code, just enough to reproduce the problem, and (b) an explanation of what "it doesn't work quite right" means—e.g., a test case with the expected and actual answers, and why you think your code should be giving the expected answer, and ideally where you think it might be going wrong based on any debugging you've already done.

Comment: I only added all of it to show what options I have for comparing the dates.

Comment: But meanwhile, if you can get the first and last date of each trip, or if you can get the first date and duration of each trip and the difference between any two dates, you don't need to iterate over all of the days; iff trip2 starts or ends during trip1 or vice-versa, they overlap.

Answer (score 3):

Let's forget about the details of your date and trip objects for a moment and just look at how to check whether two ranges overlap.

If they overlap, one or more of the following must be true:

- Second range starts within the first range.
- Second range ends within the first range.
- Second range contains the first range.

There are other equivalent formulations, some of which may feel more natural for your use case or be more efficient (not that that's likely to matter); just think it through and pick the one that makes sense to you.

You can translate that into Python as something like:

```
(start1 <= start2 <= end1 or
 start1 <= end2 <= end1 or
 start2 <= start1 and end2 >= end1)
```

Of course the actual details will be slightly different depending on your boundary conditions (whether your ranges are closed or half-open; if half-open, whether an edge day overlaps with itself or not<sup>*</sup>), but that should be enough to get you started.

Now, go back to your classes. Is there a way to get the start and end dates of each trip? If so, you should be able to write this easily.

If not, if you can get the start date and duration, and you can get the difference between two dates in days, you can rewrite the same test in terms of those values instead.

---

<sub>* While you're thinking through those boundary cases, that's a great time to write some unit tests. It's better to test it yourself than to turn in the assignment and get marked down for a case you didn't think of. (Or, the real world equivalent, to release the program and then have to stay up all night Friday debugging and releasing a quick patch because you broke your program for all of your users.)</sub>